# New line in alert typescript using html tag like ` br`

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, alert

I'm using typescript alert modal and I'm passing some text and I need to break in between those texts I've used `<br>` but it is taking as text, not as HTML tag

I've tried `\r\n` and `\n` and normal `<br\>` as well it takes as a string and shows on the modal

Please help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code snippet to help you better

Comment: Hard to help unless we can see the text you are passing and the way you are trying to render it on modal. Here is a tip - `\n` does not cause a line break in html.
You'll need to use a `<br/>` or wrap your text in a block element.

Comment: please read this before ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Neither \n is working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `<br/>` instead of `<br\>` or wrap your text in a block element.

Example Using `<br/>`:

```
sContent += sOldContent + '<br/>';
sContent += sContent + '<br/>';
```

Example using block element:

```
sContent += `<div>${sOldContent}</div>`;
sContent += `<div>${sContent}</div>`;
```

This assumes that you are trying to do this on an HTML modal. If you are referring to javascript `alert()`, then please note that `alert()` is a method of the window object that cannot interpret HTML tags.

But of course, you can use escape characters like `\t` and `\n` in alert boxes:

```
alert(
    'Dummy alert box\n\n' 
    + "\t• First list item 1\n" 
    + '\t• Second list item 2\n' 
    + 'Char\t| Result\n' 
    + '\\n\t| line break\n' 
    + '\\t\t| tab space'
  );
```